# Where do the treasure types used in the books Teratic Tome and Lusus Naturae come from?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification, treasure, osr

These books, as an alternative to the randomized treasure types and tables found in White Box through at least AD&D 1E, have a guaranteed amount of certain types of objects, and specific names for how many of each kind of object (a Trove is different than a Hoard is different that a Purse, etc.).  I'm assuming that this treasure system is codified somewhere other than these two products; if it is, where is it codified and what is it called?  If this specific system isn't codified anywhere else, that is also an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [*Lusus Naturae*](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/147685/Lusus-Naturae) and the [*Teratic Tome*](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/110459/Teratic-Tome) are for the OSR game of weird fantasy [***Lamentations of the Flame Princess***](http://www.lotfp.com/RPG/). *Caution:* That site has an illustration of a person stabbed in the eye as its logo. Folks looking over your shoulder at work might think you're visiting a site about something other than tabletop role-playing games.

This *Teratic Tome* [review](http://www.kjd-imc.org/blog/review-teratic-tome-by-rafael-chandler/) indicates that the treasure system, with its assortments, caches, and the like, was introduced in that text, providing a system lacking in *Lamentations*. This *Lusus Naturae* [review](https://docschottslab.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/lusus-naturae-review-lotfp/) indicates that text continues in the same (*ahem*) vein, making the *Tome* the original source for this system.

(I should note that I am a sucker for intuitive organization, and the *Tome* treasure types are, in increasing large amounts, *assortment*, *cache*, *coinage*, *fortune*, *hoard*, *loot*, *lucre*, *purse*, *riches*, and *trove*. Those are alphabetical, which is a good idea despite the names being a bit clumsy.)

Comment: Minor point: The Teratic Tome is listed as being OSRIC compatible, not LotFP compatible (as if that matters much in regards to these games).  I really appreciate the answer!